# pass a hidden input value to php

Tags: php, jquery, image, profile, image-uploading

i found this code to upload profile image,

http://www.phpdevblog.eu/2011-04/combined/jquery-ajax-and-php-based-profile-image-upload-without-reloading-the-page.html#comments

everything are fine. but i want to set a name file = user_id

how i pass the input hidden user_id value to the php upload file process?

```
var uploadURL = "processupload.php";
      $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a#uploadFile').file();
                $('a#delete').click(function(){
                      $('input#profileImageFile').val("");
                      $('img#profileImage').attr("src","/images/styles/profileBlank.jpg");
                      $('div#messageBox').html("Image deleted !");
                      $('div#messageBox').attr("class","success");
                      $('a#delete').hide();
                });
                $('input#uploadFile').file().choose(function(e, input) {

                    input.upload(uploadURL, function(res) {
                        if (res=="invalid"){
                            $('div#messageBox').attr("class","error");
                            $('div#messageBox').html("Invalid extension !");
                        }else{
                            $('div#messageBox').attr("class","success");
                            $('div#messageBox').html("Imagen cargada !");
                            $('img#profileImage').attr("src","/images/avatars/"+res);
                            $('input#profileImageFile').val(res);
                            $('a#delete').show();
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    }, '');                  
          });
           });
```

html

```
<div class="imageContainer">
            <img alt=""  src="/images/avatars/<?php echo $row_rs_user['user_image']; ?>" width="150" height="150" id="profileImage">
            <a href="#" id="uploadFile" title="Upload"><img alt=""  src="/images/styles/upload.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" id="delete" title="Delete" style="display:none;position:relative;z-index:999999;"><img alt=""  src="/images/styles/delete.jpg"></a>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $row_rs_user['user_id']; ?>">
            <div id="messageBox"></div>
    </div>
```

PHP upload process

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Sending a user_id via POST is not a good idea. Just use the user id from your session (I guess users must be logged in to have a user_id?), thats a lot safer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin you are using to handle the uploads, but if the form elements are hitting the PHP as they should, you simply can call

$fileId = $_POST['user_id'];

This will set a variable in your PHP Process equal to the hidden value.  Make sure you include it within the ISSET conditional as not to cause any errors.

Comment: only one element is coming to the PHP (input uploadfile) the other elements on the form, do not come, because this happens without submitting the form

Comment: Gotcha.. Ok.  In that case, I agree with John in regards to the session usage.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the information through the uploadURL:

```
input.upload(uploadURL + "?user_id=" + $("input[name=user_id]").val(), function(res) {});
```

Make sure the name of the hidden input holding the user id is 'user_id'.
Server side in PHP you can read the value of the variable with isset($_REQUEST['user_id']).